# Store users of multiple macs on network drive

Tags: network, user-account, nas

Is that a thing with macOS? I know that is (was?) somehow possible on windows.

I would like to have all user accounts of different Macs on a network drive (NAS), so everybody could log in to their own useraccount from any mac in the office.
Also the storage of the mac (besides the OS) won't be used and everybody is "forced" to store everything on the NAS, because all home folders (Desktop, Documents etc.) will be together with the user on the NAS.

Edit:
So far all user accounts are created and managed individually on the macs. We don't use mac Server and nothing else in this direction.
I want to get started with it (depending on the upcoming work this brings with it) and set it up from scratch.

Comment: Hi! Are you looking for a directory type solution where it specifies a network location for user home folders? https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/set-up-home-folders-for-user-accounts-diru31ab8054/mac

Comment: Do you have a central account management in place or are user accounts managed individually on each Mac?

Comment: @nohillside Right now they are managed individually. But I could change that if I have to set up everything from scratch.

Comment: @bmike Thanks. I'm not 100% sure if that really is what I need, but it sounds good. I will look into this

Comment: One thing to note when you do this - if your Macs have SSDs then disk access will be much faster to local drives so many users will want to use the local drives. I am a developer and had this setup and used links etc to get this done.

Comment: @mmmmmm You mean links (favorites) in the Finder sidebar? Or symlinks of the actual folders? One of the problems I'm facing is that the users aren't that advanced. And even tho I told them to store their stuff on the NAS, they still drag and drop literally everything to the desktop. So nobody else than them has access to these files and the mac gets really trashed up and full real fast. As far as I've read symlinking the desktop could bring some problems and to have the desktop on a network drive I found nothing.

Comment: Oh no don't symlink the desktop I meant something else to allow access to local drive. If the users just do web and office type things there won't be an issue but if they do video etc then the speed will matter